# Observe each element of RecyclerView (Architecture components)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to create a list of elements (each elements use databinding to set the data) and observe each one for changes. Actually I have a ViewModel with a MutableLiveData List `MutableLiveData<List<ElementModel>>`.

The thing is that in each element there are actions like upload a file or enter a password so I have to change the UI once the actions are finished or when are loading. I tried with `notifyItemChanged` in the RecyclerView adapter but the animations are really bad, it's better when you update the layout with `executePendingBindings`

Does anyone witch is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: what does `"animations are really bad,"` really mean?

Comment: The elements' height depending on the state of the element, because I'm hiding or showing views inside. So when I use `notifyItemChanged` the element resizes in a weird way, while `executePendingBindings` makes the animation perfectly

Answer (score -1):

If you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals().
Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.

```
 public static final DiffCallback<User> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffCallback<User>() {
            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
                // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
                return oldUser.getId() == newUser.getId();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
                // NOTE: if you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals()
                // Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.
                return oldUser.equals(newUser);
            }
```

User class as below

```
public class UserInfo{
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String number;

    private String name;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UserInfo(String number, String name) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;

        UserInfo user = (UserInfo) obj;

        return user.number == this.number && user.name == this.name;
    }


    public static DiffCallback<UserInfo> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffCallback<UserInfo>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull UserInfo oldItem, @NonNull UserInfo newItem) {
            return oldItem.number.equals(newItem.number);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull UserInfo oldItem, @NonNull UserInfo newItem) {
            // If this comparisons  wrong then to many UI changes in RecycleView
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChangePayload(@NonNull UserInfo oldItem, @NonNull UserInfo newItem) {
            return super.getChangePayload(oldItem, newItem);
        }
    };
}
```

please refer [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)